# Do we need to do cross browser testing of React application

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-native, cross-browser

I am testing  a web application with front end developed in ReactJS. React components will behave exactly same for a given set of properties. So I am wondering, is it worth doing cross browser testing of such app?

Answer (score 7):

See [Browser Support](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html) in the React docs. I think you can be reasonably confident that the React team has done cross browser testing on React itself, for the browsers they support. However, it does require polyfills in older browsers.

And, you will be writing your own HTML/CSS code as part of your application. You should be testing that code if you have concerns about cross browser support.